# Prove a theorem of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Please note I tried solving this problem using various functions such as f(x) = sin(x) as Sin(0) = 0 , and also f(x) = exp(x)-1 because that will also satisfy f(0) = 0 and be a C^k function. However, I am not getting g belong to C^(k-1) thing since its going all the way up to infinity. I am still getting f(x) = x.g(x) but my last part is not working, that's where my concern is.

Can anyone help me out in this? Any help or suggestions will be helpful for me and will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Define $h(t)=f(tx).$ Then $h'(t)=xf'(tx)$ so integrating both sides from $0$ to $1$ gives $h(1)-h(0)=f(x)=x\int^1_0f'(tx)dt$. Now set $g(x)=\int^1_0f'(tx)dt$ to conclude.

Comment: I understood Ur statement, but I have some questions. Will this work for all values of k, i.e. 0,1,2,3.....? By taking a look at your expressions, it looks like its going to work but still asking. Also, do we need to show that f(x) or g(x) are continuous functions? thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, how r u going to get f(0) = 0 from the expression u defined ?

Comment: Look at my answer. $f(x)=x\int^1_0f'(tx)dt$ so $f(0)=0.$ and since $f$ is $C^k,\ \int^1_0f'(tx)dt$ is $C^{k-1}.$

Comment: Yeah I am sorry for sending u the comment, I did it on my own again taking values of f and g, its working. I think we are good. Thanks!!

Comment: OK, great. But you don't choose $f$. It is given arbitrary, and the exercise is to express it as $xg(x)$ for a suitable $g$. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: yeah I figured that out long back when u solved it. Thanks!!